# Zapier shows only 100 locations from Google My Business

Tags: zapier

Zapier shows only 100 locations from Google My Business, Google Review or Google Location

Tried searching locations and remining lists were not shown

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the following.

1. Make sure that the user is the owner of the location by opening the location, clicking on the Triple Dot, and selecting"Business Profile Settings" under "Managers"; the email should be listed as an owner.

Note: The owner of the group doesn't make you the owner of the location.

2. In Zapier, When you select Locations, click on the custom tab and enter the following

locations/

You can find the location Id under "Advanced settings" of the location and labeled as "Business Profile ID". Replace  above with the "Business Profile ID" and test your trigger and it should work.